# .NET Core - JWT - SecurityTokenNoExpirationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, jwt

In the context of a **login page**, I try to build a **Jwt token in .NET Core**.

The middleware is throwing an exception:

> SecurityTokenNoExpirationException

Pretty sure everything is into place.

I followed : https://www.youtube.com/watch?edufilter=NULL&ab_channel=IAmTimCorey&v=9QU_y7-VsC8

here is the authentication controller part that creates the JWT:

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(settings.JwtSecret);
var claims = new Claim[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.RoleId.ToString()),
    // token not valid before certain date, in our case, make it valid right away
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString()),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString()),
};

var header = new JwtHeader(
        new SigningCredentials(
            new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature
            )
        );

var payload = new JwtPayload(claims);

var securityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
```

here is the startup.cs part that initializes the JWT middleware:

```
var settings = settingsSection.Get<Settings>();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(settings.JwtSecret);
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

Tell me if you need more info.

Thanks for helping me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timestamps in a JWT are represented as seconds in [UNIX epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), not as milliseconds.

[RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-2) defines the numeric date:

> A JSON numeric value representing the number of seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time, ignoring leap seconds.

Therefore use `ToUnixTimeSeconds()` instead of `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()` when you create the claims.

Comment: I'll check it out, but I realized the bearer was not sent ... I posted an angular question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169600/angular-9-typescript-headers-set-not-adding-header

Comment: Can't help for the Angular question,but I wonder why you get such a specific exception, when you simply didn't send the token?  But anyway, as soon as you're sending the token, you'll see, that the wrong timestamp format is the next problem.  And I think you should also add `ValidateLifetime = true` in the `TokenValidationParameters`

Comment: yeah I'll validate your answer then