# Angular 9 - typescript - headers.set - not adding header

Tags: angular, httprequest, bearer-token, http-status-code-401

I try to use an angular **injector to add a bearer token**

although **the code is executed, the header is not added**

there are many different codes out there, I tried some of them, they all lead to the same issue

**no bearer is send** with the request

in the below image I stopped at **clone/headers.set**, but **even after that step, the headers map is still empty**

[image]

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private appService: AppService
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add auth header with jwt if user is logged in and request is to the api url
    let authentication: Authentication = this.appService.getUserSession();

    const isLoggedIn = authentication && authentication.token;
    const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(environment.apiUrl);

    //------------------------------------- add id's
    let body = request.body;
    if(!body)
    {
        body={};
    }
    body['clientId'] = environment.clientId;
    body['clientSecret'] = environment.clientSecret;

    request = request.clone({
        body: body
    });

    //--------------------------------------- add jwt

    if(authentication)
    {
        request = request.clone(
            {
                headers: request.headers.set('Bearer', authentication.token)
            }
        );
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

thanks for helping me on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the clone() method prototype, you got an object property to set headers (named setHeaders)

```
setHeaders?: {
            [name: string]: string | string[];
        };
```

You should do as following

```
 request = request.clone(
         {
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${authentication.token}`
            }
         }
    );
```

Comment: pretty sure this was the previous code I had, I'll check it out, thanks

Comment: did not work for me either. I think if it worked with this answer, it would also work for one of those in the question.